# Standard & Spot Instance Load balancing between each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been reading up on Spot Instances but still cant find a way that is safe enough with no downtime. Will it be possible if i launch a normal instance and a spot instance then load balance between them both?

Any other suggestions? :) , i don't mind using Spot instance but the issue is that it doesn't give a warning before shutting down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to load balance between spot instances and on demand instances.  I'm doing it right now.  I'm using two auto scaling (AS) groups.  One for Spot and the other for On Demand. The load balancer is specified when you create an AS group.  You can specify the number of instances you want or choose to scale based on load.  Auto Scaling is not available in the AWS Console at this time, so there may be a learning curve to get yourself up and running with the API.

Comment: Cool, i will look at it, is it worth the $ to load balance? I'm thinking of running a Micro and a Spot Medium High CPU and just transfer most traffic to the other Spot CPU. how does the data work? does both isntance need to have same files? etc?

Comment: I think it's worth the money... But when you go into load balancing, in most cases, you have to completely rethink how you deploy resources.  Your production data will have to be centralized. So will deployment files. If this is something that you want to invest time into, I recommend learning CloudFormation.

Comment: hmm is it supporting in Singapore?http://goo.gl/GbqDU     not very sure how the load balancing should work out, as in, data, if i do a snapshot and launch a new instance then load balance, wont i miss what happened as the changes in going on, both image wont be the same in this case right?

Comment: Don't know if it's available in Asia.  Probably.  Like I said, you have to completely rethink how you deploy resources.  You will not be able to store it on your instances.